# Flutter SlideTransition begin with Offset OFF SCREEN

Tags: flutter, dart

My app is a simple Column with 3 Text widgets wrapped in SlideTransitions.  My goal is for the app to load with nothing on the screen, and then animate these Text widgets from the bottom (off screen) up into the screen (settling in the middle).

```
return Column(
   children: <Widget>[
     SlideTransition(
         position:_curve1,
         child: Text('Hello 1')
     ),
     SlideTransition(
         position:_curve1,
         child: Text('Hello 2')
     ),
     SlideTransition(
         position:_curve1,
         child: Text('Hello 3')
     ),
   ]
);
```

The problem is that when defining the animation, you have to specify their initial Offset.

```
@override
void initState(){
    ...
    Offset beginningOffset = Offset(0.0,20.0);
    _curve1 = Tween<Offset>(begin: beginningOffset, end: Offset.zero).animate(
    CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.easeInOut)));
    ...
}
```

Here you can see that beginningOffset is specified as Offset(0.0, 20.0) which does successfully position the widgets off screen.  But what happens if I suddenly run this on a tablet?  Since Offset is defined as units of the height of the widget, then this is obviously not a good way to position a widget off screen.

Since the animation is defined in "initState()" ...  I see no way to use something like MediaQuery.of(context) ... since we don't have context there.

In native iOS this would be simple.  Within "viewDidLoad" you would get the frame from self.view.  You'd position each text field at the edge of the frame explicitly.  You'd then animate a constraint change, positioning them where you want them.  Why must this be so hard in Flutter?

I find it especially curious that this exact scenario (starting an animation just off screen) is totally not covered in any of the examples I could find.  For instance:

https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/examples/_animation/basic_staggered_animation/main.dart

Seems like almost every type of animation is featured here EXCEPT an explicit off screen animation on load...  Perhaps I'm just missing something.

EDIT:  ThePeanut has solved it!  Check his "Second Update".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might want to try using the **addPostFrameCallback** method in your **initState**.

```dart
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
         // Schedule code execution once after the frame has rendered
         print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.toString());
      });
    }
```

[Flutter Api Docs Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)

**OR** you can also use a **Future** for this:

```dart
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
          // Schedule a zero-delay future to be executed
          print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.toString());
      });
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATED**

A bit of a *unusual* way to do it, but it really does the thing you need.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<Offset> animation;
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    animation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
      end: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animationController,
      curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
    ));

    Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      animationController.forward();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Don't forget to dispose the animation controller on class destruction
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          SlideTransition(
            position: animation,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DpeOMc3XgAIMyx_.jpg',
                  ),
                  radius: 50.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It works this way:

**1.** We create a **Stack** of items with options to expand any child inside it.

**2.** Wrap each **slide** you want to display in to a **Column** with center alignment of children. The Column will take 100% of the size of the Stack.

**3.** Set the beginning **Offset** for animation to **Offset(0.0, 1.0)**.

Keep in mind that **dx** and **dy** in Offset are not pixels or something like that, but the ratio of **Widget's** width or height. For example: if your **widget's width is 100.0** and you put **0.25 as dx** - it will **result in moving your child to the right by 25.0 points**.

So setting offset to (0.0, 1.0) will move the Column offscreen to the bottom by it's 100% height (this is how many page transitions work in Flutter).

**4**. Animate the Column back to it's original position after a 1 second delay.

**SECOND UPDATE**

This code calculates the offset based on the screen size and widget size.
*PS.* There might be a better way of doing this that I don't know of.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page(),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  // Set the initial position to something that will be offscreen for sure
  Tween<Offset> tween = Tween<Offset>(
    begin: Offset(0.0, 10000.0),
    end: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
  );
  Animation<Offset> animation;
  AnimationController animationController;

  GlobalKey _widgetKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // initialize animation controller and the animation itself
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    animation = tween.animate(animationController);

    Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      // Get the screen size
      final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      // Get render box of the widget
      final RenderBox widgetRenderBox =
          _widgetKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      // Get widget's size
      final Size widgetSize = widgetRenderBox.size;

      // Calculate the dy offset.
      // We divide the screen height by 2 because the initial position of the widget is centered.
      // Ceil the value, so we get a position that is a bit lower the bottom edge of the screen.
      final double offset = (screenSize.height / 2 / widgetSize.height).ceilToDouble();

      // Re-set the tween and animation
      tween = Tween<Offset>(
        begin: Offset(0.0, offset),
        end: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
      );
      animation = tween.animate(animationController);

      // Call set state to re-render the widget with the new position.
      this.setState((){
        // Animate it.
        animationController.forward();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Don't forget to dispose the animation controller on class destruction
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit: StackFit.loose,
      children: <Widget>[
        SlideTransition(
          position: animation,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            key: _widgetKey,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DpeOMc3XgAIMyx_.jpg',
            ),
            radius: 50.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That is helpful for finding the size of the app's / device's view at runtime, but that turns out to only be 1/2 of the problem.

Since the "Offset" class defines an offset using the height of a widget you're applying the offset to, then I would also need to know the height of whatever widget I am trying to hide off screen.

There must be a better way to animate a widget from off screen, to on screen...

Comment: I might just provide a complete example. Do you want all 3 texts at once to slide to the center of the page?

Comment: Actually, I'd like them to be a staggered animation.  But for simplicity, the staggering is not necessary...  The main issue I'm struggling with is just getting them to start right off screen (not some offset based based on the height of the widget which makes it very hard / impossible to know if you're off screen just enough).  Concrete example would be really helpful

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: First off all thank you for the thorough example, it's much appreciated.  One thing I still don't know is how you would animate JUST the CircleAvatar.  Let's say you did want to animate each CircleAvatar into the page with a staggered animation (slight delay between each).  You couldn't just offset their container like you have here... you need to actually offset the CircleAvatar.  But unless you statically define their height (and then use that with MediaQuery.of(context).size.height to find the Offset required)... then how would you do it :(

Comment: I just want to clarify ... what you've done here is simply to wrap the Text widgets in a Stack that fits the entire height of the screen.  That's why you can use Offset(0.0,1.0) because the widget you're animating (the Stack) fills the entire screen.

This doesn't address the root issue:  Specifying starting positions with Offset that is relative to the size of a widget means you MUST always know the size of the widget you're animating, if you want accurate placement of the widget anywhere in space.

This example becomes clear as day if you try to individually animate those Text widgets.

Comment: Added one more example. Please read the comments in the code. It's a more complex way of doing it and I personally like the first approach.

Comment: This is the right answer!  I agree with you this is complex compared to the first solution, but this new solution allows you to actually animate just child widgets.  As it turns out, that's really what I need (because they will be independently animated in a staggered fashion).  Thank you for this!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, to have the exact value of off-screen.

Screen size / 2 / widget size + half of 1 offset

**Without the half offset, only half of the widget is off-screen.**

```dart
final widgetHeight = 190;
final offsetScreen = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window).size.height / 2 / widgetHeight + 0.5;
```